# ODE and IVP: need to solve $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=1,$ I have $y=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Solve $$y''+4y=0 \\ y(0)=2 \;, y'(0)=1$$

I have managed to solve $y(0)=2$ where $B=2,$ but I'm struggling with $y'(0)=1$

Is $y'=2A\cos(2x)-2B\sin(2x) ?$

Comment: Yes it is indeed.

Comment: $y''+w^2y=0$ with initial conditions at $x=0$ has the general solution $$y(x)=y(0)\cos(wx)+\frac{y'(0)}{w}\sin(wx).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$$
$$y(0)=2 \implies B=2$$
Yes when you differentiate you get: $$y'=2A\cos(2x)-2B\sin(2x) $$
Then initial condtion gives:
$$y'(0)=2A=1 \implies A=\dfrac 12$$
So that the solution is :
$$y(x)=\dfrac 12\sin(2x)+2\cos(2x)$$